# generate PowerPivot workbook

Tags: excel, format, powerpivot

I would like to know if it is possible to generate a PowerPivot workbook programatically ? Is the powerPivot data format described somwhere ? I know that it's an xlsx file and when i unzip it, there is an item1.data which contains the encoded data - embedded in the workbook.

Regardless of what data i embed in the powerpivot workbook, be it plain text, or data coming from SQL Server, the *.data file is in the same format, and i don't know if this structure is specified somewhere.

Ultimately i would like to programatically generate the excel file with embedded data, from a variety of data sources.

Comment: Any response? My answer summarized the structure of the data.

Answer (score 0):

PP builds an internal SSAS DB as you define and creates a PP application (PowerPivot Model). The data is highly compressed and resides within the .xlsx file itself in the SSAS DB format which sounds odd, but you can verify this by creating a  PP app in Excel 2010 and save it, rename the .xlsx file extension to .zip and save, open the .zip file and go to the xl\customData directory. This .data file is where the PP data and SSAS DB model resides.

To verify again stop a running SAS 2008 R2 instance and edit it's msmdsrv.ini file located in the msas10_50 config directory by placing a value of 1 inside of the  tags, now restart the SSAS instance and it should be running in IMBI Mode now.

Create and save a copy of the .data file inside of your .zip file and rename the .data extension to .abf (Analysis Services Backup file extension) and restore the new .abf file to the SSAS 2008R2 instance running in IMBI Mode.

You can now explore the PowerPivot application's SSAS DB and even browse (pivot) on it's data in Management Studio.

This explains why you can use SSAS APIs to query PowerPivot Models since that's what the UI is using.